# Django ORM for not in case

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert below given SQL query to Django ORM.

```
select usp.user_id from Class_A as usp join Class_B as au 
       on au.id = usp.user_id join Class_C as up 
       on up.user_id = au.id where up.type not in ('A','B','C') 
       and up.end_time > now() and up.user_id = usp.user_id 
       and usp.data_enabled=1 and (usp.item_state=3 or usp.item_state=4)  
       and usp.user_id=au.id and au.is_active=1
```

I need to filter out those rows whose type is not one of ('A', 'B', 'C')

I tried many combination but I am getting wrong result because I could not implement `up.plan_type not in ('A','B','C')` in right way. I tried using `exclude()`  and `~Q()` variable but they are not giving right result because they are excluding rows after doing all join operation, I need to exclude rows while doing join operation.

I tried this

```
ClassA.objects.exclude(user__classA_plans__plan_type__in = ['I', 'C', 'D']).filter(user__classA_plans__end_time__gte = datetime.now(),**query)
```

where `classA_plans` is related name.

Please help me on this.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should show exactly what you have tried so far

Comment: @Sayse I will update what I have tried

Answer (score 0):

Conditional joins are not supported by Django ORM currently, you will have to either rewrite the query, use raw sql, or switch to a different ORM engine like SQLAlchemy.